# Linear algebra - Uniqueness of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Maybe this question does not make much sense, but I have not seen a clear explanation of this so far.
Let $V$ be a vector space. In abstract terms, what makes one vector $v_1$ different from another vector $v_2$ in that space? In other words, in what way is a vector unique? If a basis for $V$ has been chosen, I guess the answer is that two vectors are different if their components with respect to this basis are different. However, I feel that one should not have to introduce a basis to answer this question. In particular, given two abstract vectors $v_a$ and $v_b$, how would one determine whether they are actually the same vector?
To my understanding, any vector $v$ in $V$ has got an existence that is independent of any basis that one might choose to represent it in. However, I am not quite sure how to define that existence in an abstract sense. Can anyone provide some rigorous mathematical insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, $V$ is just a set with a binary operation (addition) and a map of $\mathbb{K}\times V\to V$ (scalar multiplication for an appropriate field $\mathbb{K}$). It has elements, and it is meaningful to speak of, whether two elements are distinct. This has nothing to do with it being a vector space, the $=$-relation simply works because $V$ is a set.

Now, because you have the addition structure, you have a way of checking whether $v_a=v_b$ by using the binary operation. Namely, if $v_a+ (-v_b)=0,$ then $v_a=v_b$ (this holds in any abelian group). So checking whether two vectors are equal can be reduced to checking whether a given vector is equal to $0$ and understanding how to compute scalar multiples and addition.

Of course, how to do this computation depends somewhat on the vector space. If you have a norm $||\cdot||$ on $V,$ a and some good way of computing that, you get a way of checking that two vectors are equal. As you say, given a basis (or, really, an isomorphism $V\simeq \mathbb{K}^n$ for some $n$), that gives you a method of computing the difference.

Comment: I think most given answers point in the same direction, but yours is the most general. So essentially the comparison between two vectors amounts to the comparison between elements in a set (by definition of a vector space as a set of elements satisfying certain axioms). Whether two elements $a$ and $b$ in that set are equal is an abstract comparison in the same sense as asking whether 1 and 2 are equal or "apples" and "pears" are equal. They are either equal by definition or not equal by definition?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simpler example. Suppose I tell you that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. How do you know whether $a=b$? I need to give you more information, of course. I could tell you, for example, whether $a-b=0$. Or I could "concretize" those numbers, and you could compare them yourself.

The same thing is true for vectors. You either need to be told their relationship, or concretize them, to meaningfully compare them.

Comment: So basically forming $c = a - b$ or ($v_3 =v_1 - v_2$ in the vector case) alone does not help since that only shifts the problem to comparing $c$ to $0$ or $v_3$ to $0_V$. So one needs to know by definition that they are equal or not equal.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Quantum BTW, you might enjoy this: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that “any vector $v$ in $V$ has got an existence that is independent of any basis that one might choose to represent it in” and I fully agree.

Other than that, I see nothing in your answer which is specific about Linear Algebra. How do you distinguish two elements of, say, the set of all functions from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R$? Well, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, then they are different because, say, $f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac12$, whereas $g\left(\frac12\right)=\frac14$. Actually, this set *is* a vector space, but I needed no bases to show that $f\neq g$.

Comment: Agreed, I think my question does not just relate to linear algebra. I guess it is more general in the sense of "how do you know two given elements in a set are equal?".

Answer (score 1):

A priori, in an abstract vector space there is no way to distinguish two elements. All vectors look alike, apart from the vector $0$, which plays a special role as neutral element of the sum. One has to introduce bases, thus coordinates, to compare any two vectors, or exploit special properties satisfied by the elements of the space in case they are given.

Answer (score 1):

You can study the abstract definition of a vector space $V$, and even before defining a basis, ask what can you say about a vector $\vec v_1$  belonging to $V$.

You can certainly write this,

$$\tag 1  \vec v_1 = \vec 0 \; \text{ XOR } \; \vec v_1 \ne \vec 0$$

When the scalar field for $V$ is equal to $\Bbb R$ and $\vec v_1 \ne 0$, 
consider the mapping from $\Bbb R$ to $V$ defined by

$$\tag 2 \alpha \mapsto \alpha \vec v_1 \quad \alpha \in \Bbb R$$

A good exercise is to show that $\text{(2)}$ describes an injective mapping. So given any nonzero vector $\vec v_1$ we can state that, besides having an existence as an element of $V$, it is also in a 'copy' of $\Bbb R$ inside of $V$; we can denote this set by $\Bbb R \cdot \vec v_1$.

Now let $\vec v_2$ be another nonzero vector not equal to $\vec v_1$. If, say, $\vec v_2 = 2 \vec v_1$, then you can consider the two different vectors as 'living (existing) on the same line' $\Bbb R \cdot \vec v_1$ defined by $\vec v_1$.

We can state the following elementary fact.

If $\vec v_1,\vec v_2 \in V$ and $\vec v_1 \ne \vec 0$ and $\vec v_2 \ne \vec 0$, then

$$\tag 3  \Bbb R \cdot \vec v_1 = \Bbb R \cdot \vec v_2\; \text{ XOR } \; [\Bbb R \cdot \vec v_1] \; \bigcap \; [\Bbb R \cdot \vec v_2] = \{\vec 0\}$$

With preliminaries such as the above, it is just a matter of time before we'll come to  appreciate the concept of a basis for a vector space.